# How to call Magento popup on load the page

Tags: magento-1.9

How to call Magento popup on load the page it will work on clik only

```
<a class="vip" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> VIP </a>
<div style="display:none">

    <div id="myDivID">
        <div class="popup-wrap">
        <div class="popup-txt-01"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_1.png');?>"></div>
        <div class="popup-txt-02"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_2.png');?>"></div>
          <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('proxelle/index/addme') ?>" method="post" id="proxelle">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="only-text" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" required="true" autocomplete="off"/>
            <!-- <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="true"/> -->
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" required="true" autocomplete="off"/>
            <!--input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required="true"/-->
            <!--input type="textarea" name="address" placeholder="Address" required="true"/-->
            <input type="submit" name="Go">
            <div class="popup-txt-03"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_3.png');?>"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>





<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a#fancyBoxLink").fancybox({
        'href'   : '#myDivID',
        'titleShow'  : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        //'openEffect'  : 'elastic',
        //'closeEffect' : 'elastic',
        'openEffect'    : 'none',
        'closeEffect'   : 'none',
        'maxWidth'  : 800,
        'maxHeight' : 600,
        'fitToView' : false,
        'width'     : '70%',
        'height'        : '70%',
        'autoSize'  : false,
        'closeClick'    : false
    });

    $("#only-text").on('keyup', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
   if (val.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
       $(this).val(val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,' '));
   }
});
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fancybox js :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js

Use Fancybox css :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/master/source/jquery.fancybox.css

Please make sure that fancybox js and css included and then use below code:

```
<div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
  <div id="myDivID">
    <div class="popup-wrap">
       <div class="popup-txt-01"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_1.png');?>"></div>
    <div class="popup-txt-02"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_2.png');?>"></div>
      <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('proxelle/index/addme') ?>" method="post" id="proxelle">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="only-text" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" required="true" autocomplete="off"/>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="true"/> -->
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" required="true" autocomplete="off"/>
        <!--input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required="true"/-->
        <!--input type="textarea" name="address" placeholder="Address" required="true"/-->
        <input type="submit" name="Go">
        <div class="popup-txt-03"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_3.png');?>"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {        
 jQuery.fancybox.open({
     'href'   : '#hidden',
    'titleShow'  : false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    //'openEffect'  : 'elastic',
    //'closeEffect' : 'elastic',
    'openEffect'    : 'none',
    'closeEffect'   : 'none',
    'maxWidth'  : 800,
    'maxHeight' : 600,
    'fitToView' : false,
    'width'     : '70%',
    'height'        : '70%',
    'autoSize'  : false,
    'closeClick'    : false

 });     
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks it's working is it possible to set cookie it should come only once

Comment: please check this link : http://jsfiddle.net/aVE9N/

Answer (score 1):

Just add below script. It should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#fancyBoxLink").fancybox().trigger('click');
});
</script>
```